# Использование двух контроллеров в одном виде Laravel

Tags: laravel

Имеется два контроллера. 
Первый из них отвечает за форму ввода.
Второй выводит значения. То есть данные (переменные) не имеют ничего общего друг с другом - берутся из разных таблиц.
При формировании шаблона  возникли сложности -

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/New/resources/views/bron/_form.blade.php) (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/New/resources/views/bron/_form.blade.php) (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/New/resources/views/bron/_form.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {{ HTML::style('css/app.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/vendor/jquery.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/vendor/bootstrap.js') }}
@yield('styles')
</head>
<body>

@include('partials._header')
@include('partials._nav')

@include('bron._form')
@yield('bar')

@include('nomer.index')
@yield('content')

@include('partials._footer')
@yield('scripts')
</body>
```

Врознь все работает, а вместе нет.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, вы пытаетесь передать в шаблон свойство объекта, которого не существует.

Т.е., вы где-то используете, например:

```
$data->title
```

а нужно:

```
$data['title']
```